# xamarin game app what to choose

Tags: android, ios, windows, xamarin

I have problem. I decided create cross-platform app, simple game. But I don't know how to start. What to choose Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Native?  Xamarin.Forms is only for business apps or we can create game on this?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin uses the Mono engine which is also used by Unity.  I would recommend you to create your game in Unity with Visual Studio Community to do the code parts.

Xamarin is more for apps and not so much games.  You'll be more productive choosing Unity.